# NU1100:Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (>= 3.0.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

When attempting to work with Azure functions, I get this error. I am just trying to run the HttpExample
I get the exact same error from the command as I do in Visual Studio Code. This is the code. I am a beginner at this so any help would be appricated.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The format of your .csproj file is actually no problem, it can work fine on my side. I think the key is the nuget management tool. You can have a check of th config or try to reinstall nuget tool.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I agree with Cindy's answer. **Having no entries or incorrect package source entries** in **packageSources** xml node in **Nuget.Config** can cause the error.

I have just encountered the same error when creating an **Azure Function version 4.0.1** with **.Net 6** released just a few days ago in Visual Studio Code. I do not have Visual Studio 2022 installed. I have **.Net 6 SDK** installed and use it with Visual Studio Code. You would think that the **NuGet** utility installed with .Net 6 SDK should have configured `<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />` in your **user level** or **global level NuGet settings** by default. But it did not.

I run `dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org` command in a DOS Command Prompt or a PowerShell session to add the nuget.org as a **packageSource** in my user level setting nuget.config file. That solved the **NU1100 Unable to resolve ** error.

On another note, I would say Visual Studio 2022 or its previous versions will configure nuget.org as the default package source for NuGet because I did not have to do that manually when I used Visual Studio 2017 before to download or restore NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your .csproj file is actually no problem. Your code of .csproj works fine on my side.

By the way, version 3.0.3 of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions is compatible with .Net Core 3.1. I think the problem is with your package management tool. If you use nuget, please check its configuration.

This is my Nuget.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Or you can try to reinstall your nuget management tool.