# error NU1100: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (>= 3.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 (new to c#, azure functions, coding in general)

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Errors

```
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (>= 3.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.10)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'
```

I'm working on a project to build a website and add azure function that will have a counter of how many people have visited the site. I am stuck at this point https://youtu.be/ieYrBWmkfno?t=1879. This is where I'm getting my error. I found a similar post here [NU1100:Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (>= 3.0.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829713/nu1100unable-to-resolve-microsoft-net-sdk-functions-3-0-3-for-netcorea) . I will be honest I don't know enough about what I'm doing to even troubleshoot it. I'm using vscode and git bash as a terminal. I tried:

1. Resolving the dependencies
2. Downloading and installing the .net 6.0 sdk and runtime

   - Originally I tried this with .net version 6  when I was creating the azure
     function but the video used 3.0 lts so I changed it 3.1
3. Downloading and installing the nuget

Any help would be appreciated. This is also my first post here so I did my best to follow the question guidelines

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class GetResumeCounter
    {
        [FunctionName("GetResumeCounter")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

[Code errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yfNU.png)

Comment: Have you tried with the NuGet Config Code given by Cindy & Hao Z in the reference post and you're using VS 2022 or VS Code to run the .NET 6 Azure Function Project?

Comment: @HariKrishna thanks for replying. To be honest I didn't and don't understand how to check the nuget management like she said. I did download and install nuget. What am I looking for specifically when I check for the NuGet Config? And I am doing all of this in vscode

Answer (score 0):

You need few installed tools and packages before creating & running the Azure Functions .NET 6 Project through VS Code:

1. Azure Functions core Tools [V4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)
2. .NET 6 SDK & Runtime
3. VS Code IDE, VS Code > Extensions - Azurite, Azure Account, Azure Functions, Azure Tools and C# Extensions to be installed.

Check the above tools installed by using command prompt: `dotnet --version` to check the .NET version installed and `func --version` to check the Azure Functions core tools version installed in the system.

4. Sign-in to the Azure Account in the VS Code IDE.

Here is the process of creating and running the Azure Function in VS Code:

[image]
***NuGet packages*** enhance the Azure Functions to be easier and more interactive, powerful when dealing with the dependencies and packages.
Also, check the `Nuget.Config` is present in the location of `%appdata%\NuGet\`. Paste this path in **`Run`** Command prompt and click Enter. If not available, add it.

[image]

Comment: Azure Functions core Tools V4  <br />
- Installed already
.NET 6 SDK & Runtime
- version 6.0.401
VS Code IDE, VS Code > Extensions - Azurite, Azure Account, Azure Functions, Azure Tools and C# Extensions to be installed.
- Was missing Azurite, Azure Tools, and C# Extensions. Installed all 
Also, check the Nuget.Config
- Nuget.Config file was present

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3dusU1F.png - Have you installed both SDK & Runtime files?

Comment: Yes and I installed each version of the .net 6.0 runtime (console, desktop, and server). I'm also getting red marks under my code (see code errors link in the original message).

Comment: That errors will come by default when you create or initialize the Azure Functions project and it takes a couple of minutes to restore the dependencies, built-in used packages and will go away automatically.

Comment: If you see my 1st gif file, I also got those red lines in the code and clicked on restore option came on right bottom corner of the VS code, then it restored all the packages used in the function and given clean code.

Comment: Every time I hit restore option  the lines come back